# Memory leak from boost::asio socket async_read_some operation

Tags: c++, boost, memory-leaks, boost-asio

The following piece of code has a very troublesome memory leak that I haven't been able to pinpoint, even with Valgrind.

```
void connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  if (!error)
    std::cout << "Connected to server successfully." << std::endl;
}

void read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error, 
                  std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  if (!error) {
    std::cout << "Transferred " << bytes_transferred 
              << "bytes." << std::endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 3)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: client <host> <port>" << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(argv[1], argv[2],
      boost::asio::ip::resolver_query_base::numeric_service);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = 
      resolver.resolve(query);

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::asio::async_connect(socket, endpoint_iterator,
      boost::bind(&connect_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    std::string ctxt_message = "";
    std::stringstream SS2;
    // std::vector<char> message_vector;
    for (;;)
    {
      boost::array<char, 1024> buf;
      boost::system::error_code error;
      size_t len = 0;
      /* WHAT I BELIEVE TO BE THE MEAT OF THE PROBLEM: */
      socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf, 1024),
        boost::bind(&read_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error,len));
      if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
        break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
      else if (error)
        throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.
      SS2.write(buf.data(), len);
    }
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I don't allow Valgrind to run this program until the end because it crashes my system, but after letting it run for a few seconds and cancelling the operation, I get the following information:

```
==2661== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2661==     in use at exit: 1,010,029,476 bytes in 9,619,333 blocks
==2661==   total heap usage: 9,619,375 allocs, 42 frees, 1,010,034,865 bytes allocated
...
==2661== 1,010,028,180 bytes in 9,619,316 blocks are still reachable in loss record 18 of 18
==2661==    at 0x4C2A879: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2661==    by 0x402E01: main (thread_info_base.hpp:60)
==2661== 
==2661== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2661==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2661==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2661==      possibly lost: 63 bytes in 2 blocks
==2661==    still reachable: 1,010,029,413 bytes in 9,619,331 blocks
==2661==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Any ideas?

Comment: None of the SO posts using `read_some` as the search string are helpful?

Comment: @CPlusPlusOOAandD why do you ask? Did you even read the code?

Comment: @sehe I ask because I find a bunch of posts on the Boost Asio library that could be used to compare this with what others have done, probably more so in the posted answers than the other posted questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you haven't quite gotten the idea of actor-based concurrency that Asio models.

Never in your code snippet is `io_service` actually run. So, yes, it is allowed to hold on to the pending tasks.

If you intended to /not/ execute any of the async tasks posted (?!?) you'd need to cancel()/reset() the io_service to not leak the pending tasks.

```
    resolver.cancel();
    socket.cancel();
    io_service.reset();
```

Anyways, I think you are missing the fact that async calls are... asynchronous. E.g.

```
  boost::system::error_code error;
  size_t len = 0;
  /* WHAT I BELIEVE TO BE THE MEAT OF THE PROBLEM: */
  socket.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf, 1024),
    boost::bind(&read_handler, boost::asio::placeholders::error,len));
  if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
    break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
  else if (error)
    throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.
```

Doesn't make any sense, because ***nothing*** ever assigns to `error`. The `async_read_some` won't get executed since you don't call `.run()` (or `.poll()` or `.{run,poll}_one()`) on the service object.

Here's a slightly fixed-uppy version of your program: (**Note** updated code sample in response to comments)

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct Program
{
    boost::array<char, 1024> _buf;
    boost::asio::io_service _io_service;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket _socket;
    std::stringstream _received;

    void read_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if (!error) {
            std::cout << "Transferred " << bytes_transferred << "bytes." << std::endl;
            _received.write(_buf.data(), bytes_transferred);

            _socket.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(_buf),
                    boost::bind(&Program::read_handler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        } else
        {
            std::cout << "End of transfer reached: " << error.message() << "\n";
            std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------------\n";
            std::cout << "Data: '" << _received.str() << "'\n";
        }
    }

    void connect_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            std::cout << "Connected to server successfully." << std::endl;

            _socket.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(_buf),
                    boost::bind(&Program::read_handler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

            // this is synchronous, but it could be done using async_* as well:
            _socket.send(boost::asio::buffer("GET / HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: www.google.com\r\n\r\n"));
        }
    }

    Program(std::string const& host, std::string const& service)
        : _buf(), _io_service(), _socket(_io_service), _host(host), _service(service) 
    {
    }

    int run()
    {
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(_io_service);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(_host, _service, boost::asio::ip::resolver_query_base::numeric_service);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

        boost::asio::async_connect(_socket, endpoint_iterator, boost::bind(&Program::connect_handler, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        _io_service.run();

        return 0;
    }

    std::string const _host;
    std::string const _service;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        if (argc != 3)
        {
            std::cerr << "Usage: client <host> <port>" << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }

        Program program(argv[1], argv[2]);
        return program.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here's a test run with valgrind (**Note** output from before updated code sample):

```
sehe@desktop:/tmp$ valgrind ./test localhost 22
==14627== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==14627== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==14627== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==14627== Command: ./test localhost 22
==14627== 
Connected to server successfully.
Transferred 41bytes.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2p2 Ubuntu-6ubuntu0.2
==14627== 
==14627== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14627==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14627==   total heap usage: 61 allocs, 61 frees, 7,319 bytes allocated
==14627== 
==14627== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==14627== 
==14627== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==14627== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Comment: Before you fail to run the actions :_ Somewhere before the exit point then. (Hint: **instead** fix your program to do something :))

Comment: @wyas I shuffled your code into a form that looks about what you wanted, and runs clean. I'm not saying it does much, but hey :)

Comment: fantastic work, this is much clearer now. One thing: I'm wondering as to why exactly the socket must be initiated using an extended initializer list [socket socket{io_service};] rather than [socket socket(io_service);]. Also, minor point but I changed [host(host), service(service)] to [host(host_arg), service(service_arg)] because of shadow variables.

Comment: sehe, and one more point: this code will only receive 1024 bytes and then will end. Doing a while loop around the read_some operation will have the same problem as before in terms of memory leaks.

Comment: Well. Like I said: "I'm not saying it does much, but hey :)". Of course, when you reintroduce the bad code, you get the bad behaviour back. So, don't. Here's a simple example that you can test using e.g. `www.google.com 80` (I hardcoded a synchronous HTTP request) **[Coliru link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/714b4d2fe1ac9225)

Comment: @wyas Two more notes: **(a)** the constructor parameter naming is a wide-spread idiom. If you don't like it, ok, but it's fine. **(b)** If somehow you really insist on writing the while loop, you can [use coroutines](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/coroutine.html). Beware: this is not actually reducing complexity - it just papers over it with a (leaky) abstraction. I suggest wrapping your head around Asio's model before you move to Coroutines.